# What does .ac extension refer to?

Tags: programming-languages, frameworks

I visited Avis.com, and I notice the web pages have *.ac extension.  Not familiar with this type--what language or framework is this?  This something Python-related?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's Struts 1, an old Java web framework that is usually used with the `.action` suffix, but this isn't fixed, and `.ac` may be an abbreviation of that.

This is consistent with the server name. Sun ONE 6 is a very old appserver product, long since obsolete, but it's of a similar age to Struts.

Comment: Thanks for the answers...between both your comments, I bet it is, indeed, Java/Struts.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the HTTP headers that are sent by the server when requesting the page `http://www.avis.com/car-rental/avisHome/home.ac`, I have :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO8859_1
Cache-Control: cache
Content-Language: en-US
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Mon, 05 Apr 2010 12:00:54 GMT
Content-Length: 19701
Connection: keep-alive
```

So, it doesn't seem to be Python-related ; more like some Java / JSP stuff.

Comment: It's not any java pattern that I've heard of, although file extensions mean very little in java web development, people can and do use a variety of different ones as they see fit.